# Iterating nested array and return flat array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Considering I have a nested array something like:

```
[
    {
        "uid": "j5Dc9Z",            
        "options": [
            {
                "name": 'Transportation',
                "checked": true,                    
            },
            {
                "name": 'Medication',
                "checked": true,                    
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "uid": "a5gdfS",
        "options": [
            {
                "name": 'Food supply',
                "checked": true,                    
            },   
        ]
     },
     {
        "uid": "jHab6i",
        "options": [
            {
                "name": "Package distri",
                "checked": true,                    
            },
            {
                "name": "maintainence",
                "checked": false
            }   
        ]
     },  
     {...}    
]
```

This array is rendered as a part of dynamic checkboxes and checked values are handled on checkbox onChange function. I need to create a final separate array of the options that are only `checked: true`.

Something like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Medication",
    "checked": true,                    
  },
  {
     "name": 'Food supply',
     "checked": true,                    
  },
  {
      "name": 'Transportation',
      "checked": true,                    
  }, and so on..
]
```

I did try following approach, but it confused on how to achieve this final array:

```
const category = filterOptions.filters.filter(ele => ele.options.some(option => option.checked === true)).map(item => item.options.filter(data => data.checked === true));

console.log(category);
```

But these returns result in the format:

```
0: (2) [{name: 'Transportation', checked: true}, {name: 'Medication', checked: true}]
1: [{name: 'Food Supply', checked: true}]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Please help out to resolve the same
​

Comment: `.map()` + `.filter()` + `.flat()` or `.flatMap()` + `.filter()`

Comment: @Andreas changed it. It was a typo :)

Comment: Can you please re-format your script. That "one-liner" is awful to read...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flatten the using `Array.flatMap()`, and then filter out unchecked items:

```js
const data = [{"uid":"j5Dc9Z","options":[{"name":"Transportation","checked":true},{"name":"Medication","checked":true}]},{"uid":"a5gdfS","options":[{"name":"Food supply","checked":true}]},{"uid":"jHab6i","options":[{"name":"Package distri","checked":true},{"name":"maintainence","checked":false}]}]

const result = data.flatMap(o => o.options)
  .filter(o => o.checked)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Precise and easy :)  . Didn't knew about flatMap().

Comment: You're welcome. There's also `Array.flat()`, if you need to flatten an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could map filtered arrays of wanted objects.

```js
const 
    array = [{ uid: "j5Dc9Z", options: [{ name: "Transportation", checked: true }, { name: "Medication", checked: true }] }, { uid: "a5gdfS", options: [{ name: "Food supply", checked: true }] }, { uid: "jHab6i", options: [{ name: "Package distri", checked: true }, { name: "maintainence", checked: false }] }],
    result = array.flatMap(({ options }) => options.filter(({ checked }) => checked));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use forEach():

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "uid": "j5Dc9Z",            
        "options": [
            {
                "name": 'Transportation',
                "checked": true,                    
            },
            {
                "name": 'Medication',
                "checked": true,                    
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "uid": "a5gdfS",
        "options": [
            {
                "name": 'Food supply',
                "checked": true,                    
            },   
        ]
     },
     {
        "uid": "jHab6i",
        "options": [
            {
                "name": "Package distri",
                "checked": true,                    
            },
            {
                "name": "maintainence",
                "checked": false
            }   
        ]
     } 
]

let finalArr = [];

arr.forEach(item => {
  item.options.forEach((option) => {
    if (option.checked === true) {
      finalArr.push({...option})
    };
  });
});

console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using array [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
var data = [
    {
        "uid": "j5Dc9Z",
        "options": [
            {
                "name": 'Transportation',
                "checked": true,
            },
            {
                "name": 'Medication',
                "checked": true,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "uid": "a5gdfS",
        "options": [
            {
                "name": 'Food supply',
                "checked": true,
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "uid": "jHab6i",
        "options": [
            {
                "name": "Package distri",
                "checked": true,
            },
            {
                "name": "maintainence",
                "checked": false
            }
        ]
    }
];

var result = data.reduce((a, e)  => [...a, ...e.options.filter(e => e.checked == true)], []);

console.log(result);
```